# JSPDF Export array to PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have an issue with exporting array data to PDF format using jsPDF plugin.
The first time I exported the PDF, the format was looking great.
However on the following tries, there is a random white space on the first page when exporting to PDF.

```
function JSONToPDFConvertor() {
            var sel = document.getElementById("yourSelect");
            var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
            var data = [];

            // first row needs to be headers
            data.push(["Date & Time", "Location", "Speed", "Ignition", "Odometer", "Batt(V)", "GPS"]);
            // go through cells

            for (var i = 0; i < myArr.Table1.length; i++) {


                var rowData = {};

                rowData[0] = myArr.Table1[i].datetimer;
                rowData[1] = myArr.Table1[i].location;
                rowData[2] = myArr.Table1[i].speed.toString();
                rowData[3] = myArr.Table1[i].ignition;
                rowData[4] = myArr.Table1[i].odometer.toString();
                rowData[5] = myArr.Table1[i].battVolt;
                rowData[6] = myArr.Table1[i].gpsStat;



                data.push(rowData);
            }
            var table = data;
            console.log(data);
            var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'letter');
            doc.setFontSize(9);
            $.each(table, function(i, row) {
                $.each(row, function(j, cell) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        doc.cell(1, 10, 90, 20, cell, i);
                    } else if (j == 1) {
                        doc.cell(1, 10, 450, 20, cell, i);
                    } else if (j == 4) {
                        doc.cell(1, 10, 65, 20, cell, i);
                    } else {
                        doc.cell(1, 10, 45, 20, cell, i);
                    }


                });
            });

            doc.save('LocationReport_' + text + '.pdf');
        }
```

[image]

This is normal (1st export):
[image: This is second]

This is second export (blank page):
[image]
This is third export, a noticeable white gap on top.

Anyone have experience on this issue?